# Make element sticky from certain height

Tags: css, sticky

I am trying to make the following element (which is back to top link) appear just from a certain height.

As it for now it is always displayed and I would like to appear after some scrolling or even after a fixed size.

I would like to do it with CSS only if possible.

```
<div style='z-index: 9999; bottom: 3em; right: 3em; position: sticky; width: 32px; text-align: center'>
  <a href='#top'>
    <i class='fas fa-chevron-up fa-2x'/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to use JavaScript. What did you try so far?

Comment: @WaisKamal it is can't be done without JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approximate like below

```css
.box {
  position:absolute;
  display:flex;
  top:600px; /* the height you want here*/
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.box a {
  position: sticky;
  z-index:999;
  margin:auto 3em 3em auto;
  bottom: 3em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  font-size:16px;
  pointer-events:initial;
}


body {
  font-size:50px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus consectetur ultrices arcu viverra malesuada. Donec pulvinar luctus lorem, eu consectetur felis interdum et. Nullam libero sem, aliquet eu porttitor ac, ullamcorper eget purus. Quisque tempus diam lorem, in aliquet arcu ullamcorper ut. Pellentesque non commodo tortor. Sed malesuada augue pellentesque diam aliquet, sit amet rhoncus diam mollis. Fusce justo leo, finibus eu turpis sit amet, ultrices condimentum mi. Duis at ornare eros, id venenatis neque. Aliquam blandit hendrerit tempus. Curabitur suscipit ipsum nec accumsan placerat.
<div class="box" >
  <a href='#top'>
    <i class='fas fa-chevron-up fa-2x'></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

You can also consider a mask trick to hide the element when it's not needed (there is no scroll on the page)

```css
.box {
  position:absolute;
  display:flex;
  top:600px; /* the height you want here*/
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(transparent calc(100vh - 600px),#fff 0);
}

.box a {
  position: sticky;
  z-index:999;
  margin:auto 3em 3em auto;
  bottom: 3em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  font-size:16px;
  pointer-events:initial;
}


body {
  font-size:50px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus consectetur ultrices arcu viverra malesuada. Donec pulvinar luctus lorem, eu consectetur felis interdum et. Nullam libero sem, aliquet eu porttitor ac, ullamcorper eget purus. Quisque tempus diam lorem, in aliquet arcu ullamcorper ut. Pellentesque non commodo tortor. Sed malesuada augue pellentesque diam aliquet, sit amet rhoncus diam mollis. Fusce justo leo, finibus eu turpis sit amet, ultrices condimentum mi. Duis at ornare eros, id venenatis neque. Aliquam blandit hendrerit tempus. Curabitur suscipit ipsum nec accumsan placerat.
<div class="box" >
  <a href='#top'>
    <i class='fas fa-chevron-up fa-2x'></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. Instead of mask it out when scroll doesn't exist, can you help me hide it once hitting bottom of the page (or more accurate when reaching the actual location of the sticky element)?

Comment: @user1692261 why you want to hide it on the bottom of the page? it should be there to be able to get back to the top

Comment: You are right of course. Silly question :) Thank you for your help